# Create an instance of case class B using common prefix members of case class A in scala

Tags: scala

I have a case class `A` which has all the member variables same as those in case class `B` and in the same sequence. Only that `B` has two additional member variables which follow the common ones. Code is as follows:

```
object CaseClassExample {

  case class A(x: Int, y: String, z: Boolean)
  case class B(x: Int, y: String, z: Boolean, a: Option[Int], b: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val a = A(1, "hello", true)
    val b1 = B(expand a members here, None, 2)
    val b2 = B(expand a members here, Some(10), 3)
  }
}
```

I want to create an instance of `B` using the values in `a` above, and only provide additional values. Something like this:

```
val b1 = B(expand a members here, None, 2)
val b2 = B(expand a members here, Some(10), 3)
```

How can I do it without typing too much?
Can I use Scala macros for this?

I know I can create auxiliary constructors and so on.

NOTE: My actual class `A` has about 18 member variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using shapeless

```
scala> import shapeless.Tuples._
import shapeless.Tuples._

scala> import shapeless.HList._
import shapeless.HList._

scala>  case class A(x: Int, y: String, z: Boolean)
defined class A

scala>   case class B(x: Int, y: String, z: Boolean, a: Option[Int], b: Int)
defined class B

scala>  val a = A(1, "hello", true)
a: A = A(1,hello,true)

scala> val b1 = (B.apply _).tupled((A.unapply(a).get.hlisted ::: (Some(3),5).hlisted).tupled)
b1: B = B(1,hello,true,Some(3),5)

scala> val b1 = (B.apply _).tupled((A.unapply(a).get.hlisted ::: (None,5).hlisted).tupled)
b1: B = B(1,hello,true,None,5)
```

Don't know if there is an built in by scala for this

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach. I will still wait for any other approach for a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an A as a member of B

```
case class A(x: Int, y: String, z: Boolean)
case class B(anA: A, a: Option[Int], b: Int)
val a = A(1, "hello", true)
val b = B(a, None, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to write an Apply method in case class B

```
case class B (x: Int, y: String, z: Boolean, a: Option[Int], b: Int) {
   def apply(aClass: A, newA: Option[Int], newB:Int) {
     B(x = aClass.x,
       y = aClass.y,
       z = aClass.z,
       a = newA,
       b = newB
      )
  }
}
```

Then you should be able to do

```
val aObj = A(3,"name", true)
val bObj = B(aObj, None, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to make the differential parameters optional and merge the two types:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: String, z: Boolean, a: Option[Int] = None, b: Option[Int] = None) {
  def toB(newA: Option[Int], newB: Int) = copy(a = newA, b = newB)
  def isB: Boolean = ??? // to test whether it's an A or "B"
}
```